# psutil.disk_usage('/') returns weird values

Tags: python, disk, psutil

When I run:

```
>>> psutil.disk_usage('/')
sdiskusage(total=451000901632, used=11184947200, free=77055238144, percent=12.7)
```

Used is totally wrong compared to what my laptop about page says, as well as `used + free != total`

What do each of these separate columns actually refer to?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation states](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.disk_usage):

> total, used and free space expressed in bytes, plus the percentage usage

The documentation also details some quirks that could lead to surprising results.

For Python 3, this is available as [`shutil.disk_usage`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage), with the same units.